# Angular 7, Node JS, IIS, pm2, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when upload big files

Tags: node.js, angular, file, iis, connection-reset

Can somebody help me? I faced such a problem. When I try to upload large files 150+MB to the server, the connection is instantly interrupted and this error appears [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET](https://prnt.sc/ubcphj). This happens only when interacting with the publishe API. Locally, everything works fine.

At the frontend, I use Angular 7. The selected files are stored in FormData, and the entire form is transferred to the post request. Here is a part of the code at the frontend:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-form-label font-weight-bold">{{
              'form.upload.build' | resource
            }}</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input
                type="file"
                class="custom-file-input"
                id="unityBuild"
                (change)="onFileChange($event, 'unityBuild')"
                accept="zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"
              />
              <label class="custom-file-label">{{ item.unityBuildPath }}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      unityBuild: new FormControl(null),
      thumbnail: new FormControl(null),
    });
```

```
submit() {
    this.hasSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.form.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.Loading = true;
    if (this.form.value.id) {
      this.update(this.form.value);
    } else {
      this.add(this.form.value);
    }
  }
```

The API works on node js, pm2 and IIS. Also added Multer to work with large files.
Here is a fragment of API:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './routes';
import * as multer from 'multer';
import * as os from 'os';

//Connects to the Database -> then starts the express
createConnection()
  .then(async connection => {
    // Create a new express application instance
    const app = express();

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE'
      );
      res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Authorization, Token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers'
      );
      next();
    });

    app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
    //app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());

    let tempDir = os.tmpdir();
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, tempDir);
      },
      filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
    });
    let upload = multer({
      storage: storage
    });
    app.use(
      upload.fields([
        { name: 'unityBuild', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'thumbnail', maxCount: 1 }
      ])
    );
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    //Set all routes from routes folder
    app.use('/api', routes);
    
    app.use(errorHandler);

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server started on port ${process.env.PORT}!`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

```
const router = Router();
router.post("/scenes", mdlwr.checkAccess,checkMultipart,new ScenesController().addScenes);
```

Once sent, the request does not enter the controller method. web.config on the server was added configuration below, but this did not solve the problem.

```
web.config Angular
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967290" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

```
web.config API
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967290" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, You can use node js limit 200mb. Please use this code `app.use(express.json({ limit: '200mb',  extended: true }))` , `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '200mb',  extended: true }))`, `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '200mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))`

Comment: Hi @Senthil Unfortunately, it did not give any effect. Also "extended" is not available in express 4.17.1 and body-parser 1.19.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

The problem was in the Cloudflare, API was proxied by Cloudflere and it cause the error.